# How to start the W3SVC service (IIS 7)?

Tags: iis-7

I want to preview my website added to the IIS, but all I see is the error which's telling me that I cannot run the website until the W3SVC service is not running. How can I run it ?

Answer (score 22):

Issue the following command on a command prompt (cmd.exe)

```
net start w3svc
```

Answer (score 5):

Type "Turn Windows features on or off" in your Start menu, and enable the components you need under the Internet Information Services node, or enable the IIS Hostable Web Core.

If it's already installed then open the IIS control panel from Administrative Tools, and enable it by right clicking on your computer name (on the left), and selecting start. You can also start the World Wide Web Publishing Services from the Services control panel.

Comment: You also have to make sure that the Web Site in the IIS Control Panel is running, as is the Application Pool associated with that website.

Comment: Good :) 8 more to go...